# How to change ereg($self_name, $HTTP_REFERER) to preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

As you know `ereg()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0

How to change

```
ereg($self_name, $HTTP_REFERER)
```

to

```
preg_match($self_name, $HTTP_REFERER)
// and
preg_match(/$self_name/, $HTTP_REFERER)
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match("%$self_name%", $HTTP_REFERER);
```

This will work as long as `$self_name` is a valid PCRE regular expression and it doesn't contain any `%` characters. If it does contain that character, replace it with some character that isn't in the RE.